# Symfony2, access same dispatcher accross multiple bundles

Tags: php, php-5.3, symfony

I have a symfony2 bundle that has an event, how can I get multiple other bundles to listen for that event?

Ie. how can I pass my dispatcher between bundles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `event_dispatcher` service instead of defining your own.

For example, if you're using YAML configuration files and are defining a custom service that will dispatch events, declare `"@event_dispatcher"` as an argument to your service.

From a controller, you can use `$this->container->get('event_dispatcher');` to accomplish the same thing.

All the framework internals use this provided service, and all bundles that want to fire or listen to events globally should use it as well.

Comment: how can i define a listener as a service?